# Change EditText with Button click

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I have a problem. I want to change the text from an EditText field from an other activity than the button.

Here is my main xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/articlename"
    android:layout_width="278dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Name of article"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:onClick="onClicknews"
    android:text="news\n(click me)"
    android:textColor="#FFFF"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here my MainActivity where the button is:

```
  public void onClicknews(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsActivity.class);
    String titel1 = "Trumps brutales Kalkül";
    EditText news = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.news);
    EditText article = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articlename);
    String s = article.getText().toString();
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(titel1)){
        news.setText("Hallo");
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And here my second xml where the EditText is:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/news"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="407dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I know there are similar questions but none of the soloutions helped me.

Comment: Why not send the value as a Bundle in the intent for the second activity and extract that in the onCreate and set there? Provide more information on your use case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity.java:

```
public void onClicknews(View v) {

   String titel1 = "Trumps brutales Kalkül";

   EditText article = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articlename);
   String s = article.getText().toString();
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("articalName",s);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your NewsActivity.java:

```
EditText news = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.news);

String newsName = getIntent().getStringExtra("articalName");

news.setText(newsName );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way to do this using only Android flow. Android system can always destroy activity which is not visible at the moment so your EditText may not exist.
You can create Singleton or dependency with dagger to save data between activities.